# Ignoring the users default language/locale and set an own?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

is it possible to set a locale for the app with no regard to the users language? My motivation is that I don't want the automatically translated labels of some buttons.

Sincerely,
Heinrich

Comment: Thanks for your replies. My main problem is that I don't want system buttons to be translated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Create the buttons with UIBarButton's

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title style:(UIBarButtonItemStyle)style target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
```

And define your own title / style to create your buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want certain buttons to appear in the user's language, then do not translate the button into that language.

Comment: but can you translate system buttons? My problem is especially focusing on system buttons.

Comment: System buttons are translated automatically. If you don't want those buttons to be translated, you'll need to recreate them manually.